# Search in an array of arrays (most optimal way)

Tags: python

I have this problem

```
var main_array = [['juan','blue'],['sean','red'],['ana','blue'],['alex','green']]
```

Always the names are in position 0 and the color in position 1.
I want to know what is the best way to create n lists with all of names group by colors.
I know that the solutions looks like

```
for arr in main_array:
    if(arr[0]=='blue'):
        blue_arr.append(arr[1])
....
```

But I think that could exist a better solution.

```
for arr in main_array:
    if(arr[0]=='blue'):
        blue_arr.append(arr[1])
```

An optimal algorithm

Comment: The answer is not to use arrays at all, but a hash map.

Comment: What is `var main_array`? This is not Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO, a better structure for you is a dictionary that maps color to a list of names:

```
colors = {}
for name, color in main_array:
    colors.setdefault(color, []).append(name)
```

or use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

colors = defaultdict(list)
for name, color in main_array:
    colors[color].append(name)
```

result:

```
{'blue': ['juan', 'ana'], 'red': ['sean'], 'green': ['alex']}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary to "stage" your values then use a list comprehension to give the required output.

```
main_array = [['juan','blue'],['sean','red'],['ana','blue'],['alex','green']]

td = dict()

for name, colour in main_array:
    td.setdefault(colour, []).append(name)

result = [[k, v] for k, v in td.items()]

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[['blue', ['juan', 'ana']], ['red', ['sean']], ['green', ['alex']]]
```

Answer (score 1):

To create n list with all names group by color, you can try list comprehension:

```
main_array = [['juan','blue'],['sean','red'],['ana','blue'],['alex','green']]

red_arr = [name for name, color in main_array if color == 'red']
green_arr = [name for name, color in main_array if color == 'green']
blue_arr = [name for name, color in main_array if color == 'blue']

print(red_arr, green_arr, blue_arr)
```

using match-case:

```
main_array = [['juan','blue'],['sean','red'],['ana','blue'],['alex','green']]

red_arr, green_arr, blue_arr = [], [], []

for name, color in main_array:
    match color:
        case 'red': red_arr.append(name)
        case 'green': green_arr.append(name)
        case 'blue': blue_arr.append(name)

print(red_arr, green_arr, blue_arr)
```

or store in dictionary:

```
group = dict()

for name, color in main_array: group[color] = group.get(color,[]) + [name]
red_arr, green_arr, blue_arr = group['red'], group['green'], group['blue']

print(red_arr, green_arr, blue_arr)
```